Deploying dotnet ldap application to Fedora 39
I have a webservice working perfectly on Windows but which fails with the following errors on Fedora 39.
Apr 21 15:59:09 gambit dotnet[197588]:       Unable to load shared library 'libldap-2.5.so.0' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider using a tool like strace. If you're using glibc, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: Apr 21 15:59:09 gambit dotnet[197588]:       /usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.3/libldap-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Apr 21 15:59:09 gambit dotnet[197588]:       /var/www/IFAuthenticator/libldap-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory --etc 
trying to resolve this is sending me cross-eyed trying to resolve the relevant links.
ls -l /usr/lib64/libldap* yeilds the following
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     12 Jul 31  2023 /usr/lib64/libldap.so -> libldap.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     18 Jul 31  2023 /usr/lib64/libldap.so.2 -> libldap.so.2.0.200
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 413736 Jul 31  2023 /usr/lib64/libldap.so.2.0.200
so libldap-2.5.so.0 is not evident.
but sudo dnf list available | grep openldap :
collectd-openldap.x86_64 5.12.0-31.fc39      fedora
openldap.i686            2.6.6-1.fc39        fedora
openldap-compat.i686     2.6.6-1.fc39        fedora
openldap-compat.x86_64   2.6.6-1.fc39        fedora
openldap-devel.i686      2.6.6-1.fc39        fedora
openldap-servers.x86_64  2.6.6-1.fc39        fedora
So, apart from 'how do I fix it' my question is also what made the dotnet compiler decide on this library/so ?

I managed to make progress by taking off the -r linux64 on my deployment script.  However, this has resulted in a new, equally blocking, error : The feature is not supported. This is occurring when attempting to make a connection to the ldap server.
I will reiterate that the webservice works perfectly when running in Windows, just not on Fedora.  I don't know if it is significant that the Fedora host is also the ldap server but setting the server name to localhost or hostname makes no difference.
I think probably I need to experiment with some other dotnet ldap libraries...

I do remember that OpenLDAP switched from versioned sonames to using symbol versioning in a recent release, so it might be that Fedora's system libldap is too new? Did the runtime originally come with its own libldap maybe? What are the contents of the openldap-compat package if it's available?
